# (curiosity) .htaccess RewriteCond directive

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to know what following code is doing in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(swf|thumbs|index.php|template.php)
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+).php?$ template.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request uri does not contain "swf", "thumbs" and so on

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(swf|thumbs|index.php|template.php)
```

make `/template.php?cat=etc` out of `/etc.php`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+).php?$ template.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`L` = "last rule" and `QSA` = append any existing query string to the newly created target uri.

Comment: or from `/example/cat/etc.ph` (the ? behind php)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I m not getting what is ^([^/\.]+) means Is it regular expression for any name file? can you pls explain what is ^([^/\.]+).php?$  -- (what is last $ means)

Comment: Each part in order:
`
`^` - start of line

`()` - the grouping that $1 represents
`[^/\.]` - any character that is not / or a literal .
`+` - more than one of the above character class
`.php` - obvious (though the . should be escaped, so it should be \.php)
`?` - unescaped in a regexp means 0 or 1 of the previous character (I think this should be escaped as well)
`$` - end of line.   Will push this into an answer due to lack of line breaks in comments

Comment: @PtPazuzu: Good point. The `?` seems to me to be placed by mistake. `etc.ph` doesn't make much sense. @user392406: `([^/\.]+)` means `Anything except `/` or `.`. Therefore my answer is not completely true, because paths don't match.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question about what the regexp actually means (as per my comment on the original answer above):

Each part in order:

`^` - start of line

`()` - the grouping that $1 represents

`[^/\.]` - any character that is not `/` or a literal `.`

`+` - more than one of the above character class

`.php` - obvious (though the . should be escaped, so it should be `\.php`)

`?` - unescaped in a regexp means 0 or 1 of the previous character

`$` - end of line.

You'd probably be best off reading some regexp tutorials such as:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

The first line turns on the rewrite engine

The second line says "if the request uri doesn't contain swf or thumbs or index.php...

The third line will only be executed if line 2 was true (i.e. the URL didn't contain any of those strings). It will rewrite a URL like `/123.php?` to `template.php?cat=123`. The rewrite is internal so the user will just see the `/123.php` in their browser window.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is very helpful. Can you please suggest me .htaccess tutorials for beginners which give me step by step info. I really don't know that regular expressions like ^([^/\.]+).php?$ means. Thanks...

Comment: specifically for URL rewriting this guide (part of the official Apache documentation) is great: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html